# Invoke Public function in Private field using Reflection C#

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I need to access the public function in Private field.

Example

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MainControl mainControl = new MainControl();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var frame = mainControl.GetType().GetField("CustomControl", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        frame.GetType().GetMethod("Display").Invoke(mainControl, new object[] { });
    }
}

public class MainControl
{
    public MainControl()
    {
        CustomControl = new CustomControl();
    }

    CustomControl CustomControl;
}

public class CustomControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {

    }

    public void Display()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Displayed");
    }
}
```

Here i need to invoke the Display function in CustomControl class.

But i am getting exception with the above approach. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: Do you know you can make the control public by setting `Modifiers` property to `Public` at design-time?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand reflection very well. To call `Display` you need to do these steps:

- get the `CustomControl` field as a `FieldInfo`
- get the value of `CustomControl` using the instance `mainControl`
- get the `Type` for `CustomControl`
- get the `MethodInfo` from the `Type` of `CustomControl`
- call the method `Display` with the value of `CustomControl`

You only did the first step, then proceeded to get the type of the field you just got, which is just `typeof(FieldInfo)`, then you try to get `Display` from `FieldInfo`. `FieldInfo` does not have a method like that.

I have conveniently made this code so that each line corresponds to one of the steps above.

```
var fieldInfo = mainControl.GetType().GetField("CustomControl", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var valueOfField = fieldInfo.GetValue(mainControl);
var customControlType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
var methodInfo = customControlType.GetMethod("Display");
methodInfo.Invoke(valueOfField, new object[] {});
```

Comment: If you change `var customControlType = typeof(CustomControl);` to `var customControlType = fieldInfo.FieldType;`, it would be more general